# When processor endian awareness is required?

Tags: macos, endianness

I am in Mac.

With Cocoa,

I know with normal files we can directly read or write without worrying about the endianness.

When processor endian awareness is required?

Regards,

Dhana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's a "normal" file?  If you mean text files, then yes, you don't need to worry about endianness.  If you write binary files containing numbers with multiple bytes, and if your file might possibly be read on a PowerPC Mac, then you do need to think about endianness.